How to recover funds sent to a Safe on a different network
I've accidentally sent my eth (on arb) to this watch only gnosis address:
gno:0x7C2cfDC820CDC320054F62368818a498E87B93f9
In support they sent me a loom video of how to redeploy the same address on a different chain, but the first step of trying to find an address of gnosis proxy factory gives me this error page: https://gnosisscan.io/error.html?500
So I'm stuck here

Have you tried searching the address using this format: https://gnosisscan.io/address/YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE?
Best, Louis
